# Issue while reading 2d array text file from python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am having very large text file in 2d array text file with UTF-8 encoding here is the example how it looks like:

```
[['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'],
['xyz','yza','zab']]
```

```
import ast
with open("myfile.txt", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    sentences = ast.literal_eval(myfile.readline())

type(sentences)
```

But I am getting error:

```
 ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Can you please assist here?

Comment: Try `myfile.read()`

Answer (score 0):

As @RichieV said, replace `myfile.readline()` with `myfile.read()`.
`readline` returns the first line in the document which is `[['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'],`.
`ast.literal_eval` then attempts to run that as normal python code, which raises a `SyntaxError` as the list is missing the closing `]` bracket.
Using `myfile.read` would pass the whole list statement to the evaluator.

So the final code should be:

```py
import ast
with open("myfile.txt", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    sentences = ast.literal_eval(myfile.read())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for nice explanation that worked.